# MongoDB replica sets with arbiter

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I'm trying to configure a replica set in MongoDB 3.0 with two replicas and one arbiter, but they are not working as expected. As you can see in the following pictures each instance tells a different status of the same replica set.

[image: Arbiter]
[image: Mongo0]
[image: Mongo1]

I used the following configuration:

**Arbiter**:

- dbpath=/mongo-metadata
- logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
- logappend=true
- port=27017
- replSet=rs0
- fork=true
- nojournal=true

**Mongo0**:

- dbpath=/mongo-metadata
- logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
- logappend=true
- port=27017
- replSet=rs0
- fork=true

**Mongo1**:

- dbpath=/mongo-metadata
- logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
- logappend=true
- port=27017
- replSet=rs0
- fork=true

I tried to ping each server and all of them are connected. Also, I have tried to use a keyfile, but nothing changed. What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**: I have migrated this post to: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94730/mongodb-replica-set-with-arbiter

Comment: How did you init the repl set? Also, have you tried to directly connect from each server to each other (ICMP echo_request aka ping doesn't mean the port is open...).. err, and um, this might be off-topic for SO, this should probably go to dba.SE

Comment: I used this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-implement-replication-sets-in-mongodb-on-an-ubuntu-vps). I used rs.initiate() to initiate the replica sets and the rs.add("mongoX.grunberg.com") or rs.addArb("mongoa.grunberg.com") fo the arbiter.

Comment: So you did the `rs.add` thing, but you haven't answered whether the ports are reachable..

Comment: I have executed: nmap -p 27017 mongoX.grunberg.com

And the answer was in all the cases:
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-03-08 19:42 EDT
Nmap scan report for mongo0.grunberg.com (10.133.186.203)
Host is up (0.00077s latency).
PORT      STATE SERVICE
27017/tcp open  unknown
MAC Address: 04:01:43:19:BD:02 (Unknown)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.49 seconds

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions only. Please questions related to database administration and configuration on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com). Also please don't post images when the text would suffice.

Comment: How many times did you run `rs.initiate()`? It looks like you may have run this on each of your data-bearing nodes which created distinct replica sets with the same `replSet` name. You should only run `rs.initate()` once, to create the initial config for the replica set.

Comment: Oh! Maybe this is my problem! I will try to start again.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the status of secondary are in startup state. That means they are still syncing with primary.

Also, why are you keeping arbiter when you already have odd number of nodes. Arbiter is usually kept for making the number of nodes odd so that election can be done with majority.

If you do not see it behaving properly after the sync, what is not behaving correctly?

Comment: The secondary node is in this status for more than 10 hours even there is no data to sync.

I want to have an arbiter even when I have an odd number of nodes because the machine where I have the arbiter doesn't have enough space to store a copy of the database.

Comment: Why do you want to have an arbiter at all.
The status should turn to "secondary" if the nodes are in sync. There is something wrong if it is not.

Also your mongo1 instance is down. It is not reachable as per the status. You need to check that too.